# Open and close UserForm multiple times without showing it's workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a workbook that only shows a UserForm when it runs with the following code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Application.Visible = False
  UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

When the UserForm is initialized, it opens another workbook (WHITEBOOK.xls). After data has been entered into the form and the user clicks the Submit button, the data is inserted into this workbook that has been opened (I've omitted that code, but it works)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Set wb = Workbooks.Open("S:\!Data Tracking\WHITEBOOK.xls")

  wb.Sheets("Jobs with Correct Template").Activate

  If IsEmpty(wb.Worksheets("Jobs with Correct Template").Range("A3").Value) = True Then
     Set SheetNameCellRange = wb.Worksheets("Jobs with Correct Template").Range("A2")
  Else
     wb.Worksheets("Jobs with Correct Template").Activate
     Set SheetNameCellRange = wb.Worksheets("Jobs with Correct Template").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
  End If

End Sub
```

When the user closes the UserForm, I close the form with this code, and close the UserForm's workbook also.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

  Unload Me

  For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

    If (StrComp(wb.Name, "Whitebook Data Entry (Final).xlsm", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        wb.Close
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't open the UserForm if the WHITEBOOK.xls workbook is already opened. I get a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range and it fails at this line of the UserForm_Initialize() Sub.

```
wb.Sheets("Jobs with Correct Template").Activate
```

I've tried adding a conditional when I open the WHITEBOOK workbook to check if it is already open, and if so, to make it active, but I keep running into the same issue.

The code I used to test if the workbook is open was

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim wkb As Workbook
  On Error Resume Next

  Set wkb = Application.Workbooks("S:\!Data Tracking\WHITEBOOK.xls")

  If wkb Is Nothing Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("S:\!Data Tracking\WHITEBOOK.xls")
  Else
    wb.Sheets("Jobs with Correct Template").Activate
  End If
```

Comment: Share the code where you tried to see if the workbook is already open

Comment: Also, there is nothing wrong with the approach you are taking, but,have you considered just placing the userform in the `WHITEBOOK`? If that is the book it is modifying, it is a logical place to house the code. Just a thought - we don't have all the context so obviously the decision is yours :)

Comment: @urdearboy I updated the question with the code I used to check if the workbook is already open. I guess I could modify the WHITEBOOK to have a button that can display the UserForm. The issue is that this is a shared workbook and only one set of employees needs to use this UserForm, so it'd be best to keep as a separate functionality. I would also need the button to be accessible from any worksheet within the WHITEBOOK workbook. Is there a way to create a button that will remain in the lower-left corner of the application window itself and not a particular worksheet?